# Laravel Blade foreach if relation present

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a project with Users that have Events they can subscribe to (Many to many).
Everything is working fine but I'm wondering how in my blade view I can see if the user is subscribed to an event or not.

This is my code to load the view with the relation

```
    $events = Event::with('users')->get();
    return view('dashboard.events')->with('events', $events);
```

Now I'm wondering in my view how I can check if a user already has a event subscribed and

**if so then don't show the subscribe button for that event**

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $event->name }}</td>
        <td><a href="/events/subscribe/{{ $event->id }}">Subscribe</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

## Edit 1

This is not giving errors, but also not working. I'm getting twice the a href version.

```
 @if($event->users->contains($event->id))
     <td>Subscribed</td>
 @else
     <td><a href="/events/subscribe/{{ $event->id }}">Subscribe</a></td>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work...

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $event->name }}</td>
    @if (isset($user) && Auth::check() && $user->events->contains($event->id)
        <td><a href="/events/subscribe/{{ $event->id }}">Subscribe</a></td>
    @endif
</tr>
```

Comment: I didn't pass a $user variable to the view. Should i?

Comment: You should, yes. It can't check whether the user is subscribed if there's no user.

Comment: Oh now it's working! Thank you, didn't know A $user variable would be needed. Thanks!

Comment: Speaking of, should probably add another condition to the if. Edited

Comment: Oh smart! :) I'm using \Auth::user() to identify the user

Comment: Bah. One more edit to check if the user is logged in or not, the isset only checks if the user variable was passed (even though it could be null/false/whatever auth::user returns)

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$event->users; // if you defined the relation as 'users'
```

Comment: Hmh not working, it's giving me twice the link.. I'm adding the code to my question

Comment: I got it working by adding the $user to the view. Thanks for your help!